# Secure page in frame doesn't see parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, https

I have this page http://domain.com

```
<html>
<div id="anyDiv" style="display:none">Hello</div>
<iframe src="https://domain.com/iframe"></iframe>
</html>
```

In iframe https page I have code

```
window.top.$('#anyDiv').show();
```

It works good if my parent page also https. But if it is http - it doesn't work.
What I can do?

Answer (score 0):

what about trying to load() your https://domain.com/iframe in a div ?

**HTML :**

```
<div id="anyDiv" style="display:none">Hello</div>
<div id="iframeDiv"></div>
```

**JS :**

```
var iframePage = "https://domain.com/iframe"

$('#iframeDiv').load(iframePage , function (responseText, statusText, xhr) {
    if (statusText == "error") {
                alert( "Not able to load file!!");
        }
});
```

Not sure of the result you'll get, but it could be an attempt.

Comment: I used posmmessage.js - this thing realy works even on ssl security page!